# Creating Android Location Object

Tags: android, location

I am using the Geocoder class to fetch multiple location objects by using the following code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
   List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 3);
   Address[] addresses_array = new Address[addresses.size()];

    addresses.toArray(addresses_array);
    for( int i = 0; i < addresses_array.length; i++ ){
       //create location object here
       locOBJ.setLatitude(LATITUDE);
       locOBJ.setLongitude(LONGITUDE);
    }
```

In addition, inside the forloop, I am trying to dymanically create location objects to add to an array;

How can I create blank location objects ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming you refer to `android.location.Location` use the constructor which takes a provider string and set it to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realized the string could be anything I choose. The documentation says "Location(String provider)" - I kept wondering what provider is supposed to be (gps, 3G ... ?)

Comment: GPS is one provider, "network" is another (which can mean wifi mac lookup or nearest cell tower). Those are the built-in system providers of Location object. Since it's your code that's providing (instantiating) these new Location objects, the provider string is entirely up to you.

Comment: Heh, I thought it would actually validate and/or query the provider specified. Nice one, thanks. :)

Comment: Really bad example of documentation for Android, wasted quite some time on this. My other question is suppose I provide a valid provider like gps, will it give me the current location? In other words what is the significance of it.

Answer (score 4):

That's not really what it's intended for, if you are looking to plot stuff on a google map you may want to look into the [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) class. You must use the GeoPoint class when dealing with Map [OverlayItem](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem.html) objects. What do you plan to do with the Location objects? Also you should do the getFromLocation call in a thread or AsyncTask since it is doing a remote server call.

using the GeoPoint class.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 3);
int size = addresses.size();
GeoPoint gp[] = new GeoPoint[size];
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
   Address addr = addresses.get(i);
   gp[i] = new GeoPoint(addr.getLatitude()*1000000, 
                        address.getLongitude()*1000000);
}
```

The values are * 1000000 because the GeoPoint wants E6 values. Also realize that if there are no matches the array may be length 0.

Comment: Thanks, you are definately right about doing this in an async class. That will be one of my next moves. For now I want to collect multiple location obects in an array and assiciate each one with a map button. When a location's map button is clicked, the mapview opens up showing the location.

Comment: So then you should use the Geopoint class instead of Location. updated my answer.

Comment: Excuse me if I am being silly but I just tried creating a Geopoint object but the class is not recognised. Searching this forum, I found and tried the following:                                                  GeoPoint gp = GeoPointUtils.getGeoPoint(coords[0].trim(), coords[1].trim());
..........???

Comment: The GeoPoint class is part of the Android Google Maps api. It's linked in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. I am not extending OverlayItem just Activity so I unfortunately can't use GeoPoint - too bad!

Comment: @sisko huh? To display anything on the map you will need to use an Overlay and Overlay Item. That has nothing to do with the Activity.

Comment: How about LatLong class @RobbyPond? http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html