# Android: Why does a new instance of Location require a provider?

Tags: java, android, constructor, location

I have a lot of geo data stored online with latitude and longitude and I'd like to use the distanceTo method instead of my own haversine formula.

So I need to put each record into a Location field, but here's my question: it requires a "provider" string.  Why?  What will Android do with that information?

```
    for (ArrayList<String> item : Places_Data) {
        Location itemloc = new Location("provider");
        itemloc.setLatitude(latIn);
        itemloc.setLongitude(lonIn);
        //do something with my new location
    }
```

Comment: There is no `getDistance()` method -- I assume you mean `distanceTo()`. The `distanceBetween()` static method on `Location` uses simple `double` values and may be a better choice for you.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code for [`Location`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/location/java/android/location/Location.java), it doesn't use the string to do anything meaningful. It just uses it to describe the `Location` internally. If you do [`Location#toString()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/location/java/android/location/Location.java#827), it prints out the co-ordinates, the provider and other details (accuracy, etc). That's all it's used for, internal description.

You can make the provider anything, as seen in this answer: [Creating Android Location Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945697/creating-android-location-object)

Answer (score 0):

Use correctly the way

```
package android.location.LocationManager
Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Use NETWORK_PROVIDER o GPS_PROVIDER

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER